# Posting through linkedin v2 api shows corrupt characters

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to create a post with Linkedin V2 api.

POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/posts

The post is posting fine. The issue is when characters from different languages are used. It shows corrupted (Attached in Pic)
The text that I am trying to post is: "Læs mere og støt på"
[image: Corrupt Characters]

This is how I am creating an object to post.

```
const options = {
        "author": urn,
        "commentary": text,
        "visibility": "PUBLIC",
        "distribution": {
          "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
          "targetEntities": [],
          "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
        },

        "content":{
          "media":{
            "title": "Test title",
            "id": assetsUrn
            }
          },
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false
      }
```

Is there any way to fix this issue? Tried some encoding stuff as well but all in vain. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've contacted the linkedin developer team and it seems to be and issue at their end which is fixed now.